# handle errors about DefaultcacheManager flutter

Tags: flutter, caching, package, runtime-error, handle

App should download a video via mobile network. I control the internet connection with connectivity_plus package. but when internet connection become weak, I am getting this error at `var file = await  DefaultCacheManager()`. How can I handle with this error?

Exception has occurred.
ScaffoldFeatureController (Instance of 'ScaffoldFeatureController<SnackBar, SnackBarClosedReason>')

```
Future<void> _downloadAndCache() async {
    if (_connectionStatusMobile == "ConnectivityResult.mobile") {
      var file = await DefaultCacheManager()
          .getSingleFile(url)
          .onError((error, stackTrace) {
        DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
        setState(() {
          isDownloadedError = true;
        });
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(_buildContext!).showSnackBar(
          throw SnackBar(
            content: Text(error.toString()),
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
          ),
        );
      }).timeout(const Duration(minutes: 3), onTimeout: () {
        DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
        setState(() {
          isDownloadedError = true;
        });
        throw ScaffoldMessenger.of(_buildContext!).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text("İndirme Tamamlanamadı."),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          ),
        );
      });
      _videoController = VideoPlayerController.file(file)
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          setState(() {
            isDownloaded = true;
            _videoController!.play();
            _videoController!.setLooping(true);
          });
        });
    }
  }
```